# How to execute an initial query that is not affected by the the configuration changes

Tags: android, mvvm, constructor, viewmodel, dagger-2

I need to execute an initial query in the ViewModel that is injected by dagger2 using ViewModelProvider.Factory,  I could do it in the fragment but in this case, when rotating the screen the activity will be re-created and the initial query will be executed again and I don't want this behavior, I want to see the same data I was viewing before rotating.

**Possible Solution**
I can define a boolean variable in the ViewModel and write this logic:

_ViewModel

```
var isScreenRotated = true
```

_Fragment

```
   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        if (searchViewModel.isScreenRotated) {
            searchViewModel.isScreenRotated = false
            searchViewModel.executeSearch("fruits", 1)
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the code here for us to better understand what you want.

Comment: see the edited post, I am actually asking if I am able to execute code in the constructor of an injected ViewModel, As I want to execute an initial query as soon as the app launches, but I don't want it to be affected by the configuration changes, so I don't want to execute the initial query again when I rotate the screen.

Comment: You dont need to execute it in the init of the viewmodel, just add a method and calles from the activity or fragment. If you need it on application level that is another story.

Comment: @DevMike01, I am thinking about it I definitely can't execute the initial query in the constructor of the ViewModel since I will have to use the ViewModel itself in the query, so the only way is the one that I wrote in the question.

Comment: @cutiko but in this way, the method will be called and executed again after rotating the screen since the activity will be recreated.

Comment: You can add the equality control to the value of the livedata-object in the viewmodel.
if (livedata-obj.value == somedata) return

Comment: Though I still don't understand what you're trying to achieve because I'm not seeing any constructor injection here. Anyways, if you want to do something once in an activity lifecycle, you can always check for `if(savedInstanceState == null){}` inside your `onCreate(Bundle)` method. The `savedInstanceState` is always empty if you're coming into the activity for the first time, but if you're rotating, it won't be null.

Comment: @DevMike01 your recommendation will fail after low memory condition. After low memory, the Activity runs for the first time, but `savedInstanceState != null`. So the initialization will NEVER run during your app's execution. Please stop spreading myths that break apps.

Answer (score 0):

> when rotating the screen the activity will be re-created and the initial query will be executed again and I don't want this behavior, I want to see the same data I was viewing before rotating.

That's why Room gives you `LiveData<List<T>>` that you can store in your `ViewModel`, so that on re-subscription the data is not re-fetched.

You don't need to care about whether screen rotates or not if it doesn't trigger a reload if the data already started loading or has already loaded.

If you need custom behavior, extend `MutableLiveData` and track the loading state yourself (start loading in `onActive` if you haven't started loading yet).

Comment: Thanks, that's definitely true, but I think you did not understand what I am trying to do I am trying to execute an initial query when the app starts the first time so I want the user to see list of photos at the very beginning then the users can search for any category they want, this query was written in the fragment and after rotating the screen the onViewCreated will be called again leading to execute the initial query again. So the possible solution that I've written in the question is not the best but it works.

Comment: That's why instead of triggering data load in `onCreateView`, you trigger it in `MutableLiveData.onActive` which would be triggered by starting to observe it, but it would not be triggered again if it's already loaded assuming that the LiveData is kept in the ViewModel. I think you just didn't understand my answer. :/